# How to correctly implement a custom number-like class in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, numbers

I am currently trying to implement my own `UnsignedInt`. I would like to implement this correctly so that it fits into the whole Scala type & class system. However, I am really confused by all the classes that fit into Number.

With which class(es) do I need to work: `Numeric`, `Integral` or `ScalaNumber`? Or something completely different? What classes and/or traits should my own class implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: don't implement your own, use the [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) one :) Otherwise, you should implement `Integral` (which includes `Numeric`). Note that your type shouldn't *extend* it; you need implicit values in the companion object, i.e.

```
class UnsignedInt { ... }

object UnsignedInt {
  implicit val UIntIntegral: Integral[UnsignedInt] = ...
}
```

You should also consider making your class a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: Is `Integral` enough as is? Or do I need others as well? And are there other implementations than Spire? (Thanks for the link though!)

Comment: `Integral` will give you all the standard number operations and integer division. You probably want `Ordering` as well. There is https://github.com/nystrom/scala-unsigned as well, but it isn't maintained.